# Postgres Integer[] store using JDBI

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbi

I want to store the arrayList into **postgres** database where the `dataType` is `Integer[]`. I am using **JDBI**.

Something like :

```
JDBI.handle().createStatement("insert into table(column_a) values (?)")
.bind(0, arrayList)
.executeAndReturnGeneratedKeys(IntegerColumnMapper.PRIMITIVE)
.first();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method getConnection() in Handle class that returns object of Connection class which has a method createArrayOf("Integer", your list), this returns Array which you can use as bind parameter.

`.bind(parameterno, handle.getConnection().createArrayOf("Integer", your list);)`